# How do you kill a (window free) process in AHK?

Tags: process, autohotkey, pid

I have a windowless process I want to kill with AutoHotkey. (I could know anything, e.g. the PID.)

For example I have tried WinKill, eg with

```
WinKill , ahk_pid %p_id%
```

Nada. Anything else?

Comment: Why would you use `WinKill` to kill a **process**? Use `Process, Close` intead.

Comment: Thanks, `Process, Close , %p_id%` works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
Process, Close, %PidOfwindow%
```

Comment: There is no *window*, please refer to the question's title. Furthermore, windows never possess a PID, processes do.

Comment: Can this be changed to `%process_id%` or `%p_id%`?